# Return minimum date from other table based on conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having a hard time writing am SQL query to return the minimum date from a table.
Table 1 (planning) contains the conditions when "HP" is met for each term.
Table 2 (realisation) contains whether or not an address is HP or not.
So the endresult should be the minimum date from the realisation table when the sum of ishP reaches the terms corresponding to that contractor.

**Planning**

| term | min_HP | contractor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | bam |
| 2 | 200 | bam |
| 1 | 100 | spie |
| 2 | 400 | spie |

**Realisation**

| contractor | realisation_date | isHP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bam | 2020-01-4 | 1 |
| bam | 2020-01-8 | 0 |
| bam | 2020-01-20 | 0 |
| spie | 2020-01-7 | 0 |
| spie | 2020-01-8 | 0 |
| spie | 2020-01-9 | 0 |

I really tried multiple SQL queries, but I can't manage to get it done. Can anyone tell me how I should do this?

I tried variations like this one, but it didn't give the expected result:

```
SELECT
p.*
, (select min(realisation_date) from realisation r where r.contractor = p.contractor having sum(isHP) >= p.term)
FROM planning p
```

**expected result**

| term | min_HP | contractor | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | bam | 2020-08-01 |
| 2 | 200 | bam | 2020-10-01 |
| 1 | 100 | spie | 2020-04-01 |
| 2 | 400 | spie | 2020-12-01 |

Comment: What is the expected result for the above samples?

Comment: all rows show the same date (2020-01-4 in this case)

Comment: Please post the example of expected results in your question, as you did for the two tables, so it's more visible to anyone trying to help answer.

Comment: Hmm, that's gonna be a problem if i have to write 100 rows in the tables haha. The expected result should be table planning with the date from realisation when isHP reaches 100 / 200 for BAM or 100 / 400 for spie

edits: typo's with tablenames

Answer (score 0):

I did not fully understand your question, the context is not clear. Although the below query can help you I believe.

```
SELECT planning.* 
    FROM 
    planning,
    (SELECT contractor, sum(isHp), min(realisation_date) FROM realisation
     GROUP BY
        isHp,
        contractor,
        realisation_date
    ) AS filter_realisatioN
    WHERE
      planning.contractor = filter_realisation.contractor
      AND filter_realisation.isHp >= planning.term
```

Comment: Tnx Arun, i'll try this and come back to you

Comment: Arun, shouldn't the SELECT be planning.*, filter_realisation.realisation_date?

Comment: If you want to get the date along with the other data then YES. And just let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables and compute the running total per contractor per term. Then aggregate to find the date where threshold is met.

```
with data as (
    select p.term, p.min_HP, r.contractor, r.realisation_date,
        sum(r.isHP) over (
            partition by p.term, r.contractor order by r.realisation_date) as HP
    from realisation r inner join planning p on p.contractor = r.contractor
)
select term, min(min_HP) as min_HP, contractor,
    min(case when HP = min_HP then realisation_date end) as "date"
from data
group by term, contractor
```

This will return a row for each term and contractors regardless of whether "min_HP" is ever matched.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4066c526d9aa68057ead38628ef8f8c5